# Is there a way to create custom ListCells using fxml file in tornadofx?

Tags: kotlin, javafx, fxml, tornadofx

Is there a way to create custom ListCells of ListView using fxml files in tornadofx?

I have a fxml file `CustomListCell`:

```
<HBox>
    <Label text="File name"/>
    <ImageView fitHeight="18.0" fitWidth="18.0" pickOnBounds="true"/>
    <stylesheets>
     ...
    </stylesheets>
</HBox>
```

And I have `CustomListCell.kt` for this fxml. I want to do something like this:

```
val customList = ListView<CustomListCell>()
customList.add(CustomListCell(name, image))
```

How to implement `CustomListCell.kt` for this purpose?

Comment: You shouldn't use UI classes (`CustomListCell`) as the *data* type for your `ListView`. Create a class encapsulating the name and image, and use that as the type for the `ListView`. Then set a `cellFactory` on the `ListView` that generates the `CustomListCell` instances to display it. I don't know kotlin, so I can't answer this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know why you thougt it was a good Idea using fxml here, but with this example you can have the result you are looking for:

```
class Example: View("Example") {
    val listofitem = FXCollections.observableArrayList<TextImagen>()

    override val root = vbox {
        listofitem.add(TextImagen("Car","car.png"))
        listofitem.add(TextImagen("Apple","apple.png"))
        listofitem.add(TextImagen("Pencil","pencil.png"))

        listview<TextImagen>(listofitem){
            cellFormat {
                graphic = cache(it){
                    hbox {
                        label(it.name)
                        imageview(it.url){
                            fitHeight = 18.0
                            fitWidth = 18.0
                            isPickOnBounds = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class TextImagen(val name : String, val url : String)
```